# display items on same line using bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display a label control, a text box and a button in the same line and somehow the label control is coming in two lines. I am using bootstrap. How can I display the label control in one line:

```
<div class="col">
     <b>Please add new box</b> 
    </div>
         <div class="col"><asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
         <div class="col"><telerik:RadButton ID="btnAddBox" runat="server" Text="Add Box"></telerik:RadButton></div>

         <div class="col">
             <b>Please add new Folder</b> 
         </div>
         <div class="col"><asp:TextBox ID="txtNewFolder" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
         <div class="col"><telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Add Box"></telerik:RadButton></div>
           <div class="col">
       
    </div>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I want "Please add new Box" and "Please add new Folder" on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used 6 `cols` so each column is taking width of `2 cols` by default. And as the text is longer so it won't fit in that particular width and hence will be broken into 2 lines.
What you can do is increase the width for **label** cols, for which you'll have to specify col span value for each div. It will be something like that:

```
<div class="col-3">
 <b>Please add new box</b> 
</div>
     <div class="col-2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
     <div class="col-1"><telerik:RadButton ID="btnAddBox" runat="server" Text="Add Box"></telerik:RadButton></div>

     <div class="col-3">
         <b>Please add new Folder</b> 
     </div>
     <div class="col-2"><asp:TextBox ID="txtNewFolder" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
     <div class="col-1"><telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Add Box"></telerik:RadButton></div>
```

That's one way to go. You can always use `flex` property with `flex-wrap: nowrap`, or make use of `word-break` property.
I hope you get the idea.